# How to catch error on window.location.href ("url") in IE on html

Tags: javascript, html

URL is opening when u enter manually on address bar of IE. But while we add the url into javascript with html file. when opening html file is not working. shows some bootstrap error. On other hand, this html file is opening without error on Edge,Chrome & firefox browsers. can anyone face this same problem?
Webbrowser control on winforms using C#.

### Code is here:-

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function Redirect() {
         window.location.href = "https://www.dream11.com";
       }

    <input type='submit` value='purchase' onclick="Redirect();" />        
  </body>
</html>
```

output as URL needs to loaded without any errors.  'C#,Javascript'people provide me idea to stop the solution

Comment: have you tried `try..catch` ?

Comment: Is this definitely your full and real code? Now I formatted the code to be readable it comes obvious that you have not closed your `<script>` tag with a `</script>`. Some browsers may be more forgiving of this than others...but I'm quite surprised it works at all to be honest. Also you seem to have a typo - `<input type='submit\`` should be `<input type='submit'` . Otherwise the quote mark is not closed.

Comment: And I have no idea how you think a C# programmer (assuming they didn't also know JavaScript) could help you with this. C# is not involved in any way at all. You mention the "webbrowser" control...but this just loads a web page inside your form using whatever your default renderer is. C# doesn't actually execute any of this.

Comment: Lastly...what even is the point of this JavaScript? You could replace the whole thing with `<a href="https://www.dream11.com">Purchase</a>`, no JavaScript required. If you want it to look like a button (even though it's a hyperlink) then you can use some CSS.

Comment: thanks Maielo, try catch is not working bcoz i try to load the url on IE7. but its shows some dynamic errors of bootstrap.

Comment: ADyson - no script errors . here i am unable to post without errors due to stackoverflow vaildators on submit the questions. write simple code to windows.location.href("URL") i m getting error dynamic bootstrap errors. i am unable to post exact "URL" due to company policies

Comment: function Redirect() {
                   window.location.href = "https://store.hp.com/us/en/cat/ink--toner---paper?jumpid=in_dir_sim";
               }; this is the exact url which i call try to load on IE  which results bootstrap error but its works fine on all other browsers like Edge,Chrome & Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Try using input type button rather than input type submit. It will work please try this.

Comment: No, its not a solution

Comment: Try using a input type button rather than input type submit .try this please

Comment: sure.Because the submit type is submitting your data and not redirecting .I also faced this before. :) @MariappanGPillai